# os-prober not detecting distros mounting ESP as /boot

Tags: grub2

I'm dual booting two distros that mount ESP as /boot instead of /boot/efi.

It seems to me that os-prober works by checking every partition for /boot, and so if it finds it empty, it doesn't consider it an OS. So when I run os-prober from either distro, the other one is not detected.

There are a couple of tiresome workarounds I can think of like temporarily mount ESP to both partitions or just copy files to the empty /boot so that os-prober detects it.

Is there a way to add a fixed menuentry to grub? so that `grub-mkconfig` always include it, even if os-prober doesn't detect it as OS.

Comment: What you describe is consistent with os-prober being disabled. Have you checked that you have a line in `/etc/default/grub` that results in it being disabled. You should have a line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` that is not commented out

Comment: I have turned off os-prober for years and just added boot stanzas I want into 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus One example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive Configfile to another grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359

Comment: @PonJar Yes. I didn't test os-prober from grub. I tested it directly by running `os-prober`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the outcome if you enabled os-prober to see if grub-mkconfig then detected the other OS and gave you a new entry in your grub menu. I’ve never seen a question where grub has a problem detecting another Linux distro although there are loads about not detecting Windows.

Comment: Ofc I couldn't discover the bug without trying out grub first: `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false grub-mkconfig > /dev/null`.